How to Determine Subject-Object Placement in SPARQL Triples?
I'm currently working on a project involving LLMs and SPARQL queries, particularly focusing on prompting LLMs to translate natural language questions into SPARQL queries. However, the model encounters challenges with determining the correct placement of entities as subjects or objects in SPARQL triples.
For instance, in some cases, the predicted query generated by my LLM model incorrectly swaps the subject and object compared to the gold query. Here are a couple of examples:
Golden query:
SELECT DISTINCT ?answer WHERE { ?answer wdt:P870 wd:Q131168 }

Predicted query:
SELECT ?answer WHERE { wd:Q131168 wdt:P870 ?answer }

Golden query:
SELECT ?answer WHERE { wd:Q46805 wdt:P276 ?X . ?X wdt:P2184 ?answer }

Predicted query:
SELECT ?answer WHERE { wd:Q46805 wdt:P2184 ?X . ?X wdt:P276 ?answer }

The prompt encloses examples, target question to answer, gold entities/relations of the question with the associated labels
how to determine when entities should be placed as subjects or objects in SPARQL triples? Are there specific rules or strategies I should consider to ensure the correct placement?
Also for a human how to understand when a specific entity must be placed as subject or object of the triple?
Any insights or resources on this topic would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

there are some research papers and projects out now which do few shot prompting etc. to convert NL to SPARQL. Did you read any of those or do you try to start from scratch? And yes, it's difficult, because usually there are two steps an LLM or in general any QA system does have to solve: 1) generate the correct query structure 2) place the correct entities. Both steps are indeed difficult by its own. Detecting the correct entity type needs schema information. And even then, it depends on the KG which "direction" of a triple would be correct.

No LLM can or will keep all Wikidata facts inside it for lookup as RDF. And for placing choosing the correct Wikidata identifiers, it turned out by state of the art that this is way to hard because those are just IDs. Most approaches mitigate this by using an entity lookup process for step 2), then pass those entities ( or entity candidates) to the LLM in the prompt.

I am not starting from scratch, it's already some months I am working on it. I read tons of papers but the majority use fine-tuning which is not suitable for my project because it focuses on prompting.
To mitigate the 2 problems you talked about I managed to address the correct query structure by giving similar examples and concerning step 2 I give the gold entities/relations in form of URIs along with the associated label. @UninformedUser

For example:
"""
Question: Which is the instrumentation of tuba?
Entities:
http://www.wikidata.org/entity/q131168 (tuba),
Relations:
http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/p870 (instrumentation),
Query:
"""
However the problem is mitigated just in part
@UninformedUser
